# How to Create a Sticky headerToolbar in FullCalendar React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, calendar, fullcalendar, sticky

I'm working with the FullCalendar React component and would like to implement a sticky headerToolbar. My goal is to ensure that the header with its toolbar remains visible at the top of the calendar, even when users scroll down through a long list of events.

I've reviewed the documentation and tried various CSS approaches, but I haven't achieved the desired sticky effect for the headerToolbar. It seems that the stickyHeaderDates option doesn't work as expected in my case.

Can someone please provide guidance or a code example for making the headerToolbar sticky in the FullCalendar React component? I'm using Next.js with TypeScript for my project.

Any assistance or insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS to achieve this effect and here is how you can approach it.

```
<div className="calendar-container">
      <FullCalendar
        plugins={calendarOptions.plugins}
        headerToolbar={calendarOptions.headerToolbar}
// add more options based on your needs
      />
    </div> 

Apply css
.calendar-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fc-toolbar.fc-header-toolbar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and assistance. 

At first, I applied the styling you provided in my SCSS file, but it didn't work. 

However, when I placed it directly in the fullCalendar component, it started working.